# how do I set .css backgroud url of a select box in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a select box and I would like to set its background url in jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    $('select').css({
        ("background", "url("+site_url+"/img/select-arrow.png)")
    });
});
```

This code doesn't work

Comment: Styling select tags, at least in a cross-browser way, is pretty much a none starter. There's plenty of discussion on this throughout the web, not least here on SO. There are vendor prefixes in some browsers for styling these (along with other form controls such as checkboxes), but there's no browser consistency. The alternative is to use a JavaScript-powered dropdown script rather than a native select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply had to many brackets in your json object being passed as options to the css function. Modify your jQuery to look like the below code and it will work.

```
$('select').css({
    "background-image": "url('"+site_url+"/img/select-arrow.png')"
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers cannot render background in select itens.
I suggest to use a solution with html and css instead a native dropdown menu.

Try bootstrap dropdown:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns